# MySQL select issue with duplicate results

Tags: mysql, grouping

So, let's say I have a MySQL table called `questions` with the following layout and data:

```
id    user_id    answers    created
1     1          35         <unix_timestamp>
2     1          30         <unix_timestamp>
3     1          25         <unix_timestamp>
4     2          20         <unix_timestamp>
5     2          15         <unix_timestamp>
6     3          10         <unix_timestamp>
7     4          9          <unix_timestamp>
8     5          8          <unix_timestamp>
9     6          7          <unix_timestamp>
10    7          6          <unix_timestamp>
```

At this moment I do a simple query, to get the 5 most answered questions for the last two days:

```
SELECT * FROM  `questions`
         WHERE `created` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-86400*2
         ORDER BY `answers` DESC
         LIMIT 5;
```

It works fine, but in some situations the result of this query has questions only from one or two users, when someone very popular has asked their followers a lot of questions and received answers within two days. Now I need to change the query, to get only one result per user.

In other words, now the result on the table would be:

```
id    user_id    answers    created
1     1          35         <unix_timestamp>
2     1          30         <unix_timestamp>
3     1          25         <unix_timestamp>
4     2          20         <unix_timestamp>
5     2          15         <unix_timestamp>
```

I need to change the query to get the following result:

```
id    user_id    answers    created
1     1          35         <unix_timestamp>
4     2          20         <unix_timestamp>
6     3          10         <unix_timestamp>
7     4          9          <unix_timestamp>
8     5          8          <unix_timestamp>
```

I have tried some stuff I found on the internet, but nothing worked for me. I am not even sure if I need to use grouping, join, subquery, or maybe even something else.

Comment: It looks like you are asking on Stack Overflow about how to create an SO-like web site!

Comment: Nope. It's just a random coincidence :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User variables to emulate row number

```
SELECT id, user_id, answers,created FROM (
    SELECT
         id, user_id, answers,created, 
        @rank:= IF(@user_id = user_id, @rank+ 1, 1) AS rank,
        @user_id := user_id  AS x
    FROM t
    ORDER BY user_id,answer DESC
) AS y WHERE rank <=1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This one is very close to the right answer, thanks, but I still get duplicates. I had to modify the query a bit, because I need to order the results descending by answers number, and I get duplicates in the situation when I have one user coming first, then another one, and then the first one goes again with another question and `@rank` drops to 1 as it would be just some other user.

Comment: @AndrewK. Edited so the users are contiguously ordered.

Comment: Omg it really worked. THIS is the correct answer! I am not sure about performance, but for now it seems to work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use Group by to get the answers per user:

```
select id, user_id, answers from questions
where answers in (
  select max(answers) as answers from questions
  where `created` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-86400*2
  group by user_id
);
order by answers desc
limit 5;
```

Here is the example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5c54/13/0)

Comment: From the last example, it seems that the PO wants the max of answers, not the sum.

Comment: How is this answering the question,where are the rest of the columns.

Comment: Yeah, this wont work. I need the question with max answers, not the sum, and I also need the `id` column.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you please check again?

Comment: Your answer does not work if the number of points is not ordered the same way as the id. See a counter example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5c54/1 . The left-most column should be 3, 4, 6 instead of 1, 4, 6 .

Comment: @Akira thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-SELECT to filter out all non-max answers for each user:

```
select q.* from
    questions q,
    (select user_id, max(answers) max from questions group by user_id) r
where
    q.user_id = r.user_id and
    q.answers = r.max
order by q.answers desc limit 5;
```

Comment: Already found the solution, but will try this also, to see the performance.